# Read custom map key using Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, objectmapper

Using this input

```
    {
      "personId": "uhqwe-8ewn-3129m",
      "infoPerson": {
        "name": "john",
        "age" : 35
       }
    },
    ....
```

And this POJO

```
public class Person {
  private String name;
  private int age;
  //getter/setter
}
```

I need to read it as

`private Map<String,Person> pMap;`

using the **personId** as the map key.

Is there a way to do it with jackson annotation?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible.
You can read a list and then convert it to a map.

Something like this

```
Map<String, Person> map = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getPersonId, person -> person));
```